# how can I find the ubuntu username and password for ssh from my windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssh, passwords, username

I used the user info for the only account on my ubuntu laptop, but it keeps saying incorrect password.
I even used the username that comes up on the terminal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure password authentication is even _enabled_ on the SSH server side? Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: You should provide us your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Ubuntu account is authorised for ssh. Check if it belongs to the ssh group. If not, you'll need to add the user to the ssh group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).